# Prove the sequence $\frac{1}{a_n}=1+2f(n)-a_{n-1}$ contains every positive rational number exactly once.

Tags: induction, recursion

For a positive integer denote by $f(n)$ the largest integer $k$ with $2^k | n$. Let $a_0=0$ and consider the sequence given by $\frac{1}{a_n}=1+2f(n)-a_{n-1}$. Prove that this sequence contains every positive rational number exactly once.

I started with the following:

By the inductive hypothesis, assume that there is some set $S$ with the elements $\{a_0, a_1,..., a_n|a\in\mathbb{Q^+}\}$ such that no $a_i = a_j$ for distinct $i,j $ $(0\leq i,j\leq n)$.

Now we need to prove $a_{n+1}$ is a positive rational and not equal to any other element in $S$. At this point I'm having some troubles. It's easy to see that $a_{n+1}$ will always be a rational, but how do you prove that it will always be positive with the $f(n)$. And for the second part of the inductive step, I tried a proof by contradiction, assuming there was some $a_k = a_{n+1}$. I kept hitting dead ends at this point.

Comment: For $n\gt 1$, if $n$ is even, $f(n+1)=0\implies a_{n+1}=\dfrac 1{1-a_n}$. If the sequence $(a_n)$ contains every positive rational number, there must exists some $n$ such that $a_n>1\implies a_{n+1}<1$. The problem is that $(a_n)$ may contain negative rational terms. For instance, $\Bbb Q$ contains every positive rational number, but it also contains negative rational numbers. 
Let $a_n\in \Bbb Q^+$. Assume there is some $m\gt n$ such that $a_m=a_n$. Then $2f(m)-a_{m-1}=2f(n)-a_{n-1}\implies a_{m-1}-a_{n-1}=2(f(m)-f(n))$. If $f(m)=f(n)$, by induction we have $a_{m-n}=a_0=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Consult [OEIS A002487](https://oeis.org/A002487) "Stern's diatomic sequence" for some good ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You prove that $a_{2n+1}>a_{2n}$, which eventually leads to proving $a_{2n}<1$ and $a_{2n+1}>1$. This ultimately solves the positive rationals issue and leads to showing no repetitions exist within the set $S$.